# Simulate `property` in Java: how to use public field as property?

Tags: java, properties

In [playframework](http://playframework.org), it uses javassist library to let the public fields of a class can be used as `property`.

See the example:

```
public class User {
    public String name;
}

User user = new User();
user.name = "Freewind"
System.out.println(user.name);
```

In compilation time, play enhanced the bytecode with javassist, the final code is similar to:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return this.name; };
    public void setName() { this.name = name; };
}

User user = new User();
user.setName("Freewind");
System.out.println(user.getName());
```

You can see not only the field `name` has getter and setter, but also the invocations of it changed to getters and setters.

I wonder if there is any other way to do the same (use other things than javassist)?

I found [Annotation Processing Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html), but I'm not sure it can do it.

Or aspectj? Or something else?

Comment: Are you asking for other tools that compete with javassist?

Comment: I want to know any tool can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/), which does something similar, but with annotations. With project lombok you do need to use the getters and setters in your own code.

Comment: I've checked that. Yes, it can generate the getters/setters, but we  can't use the field direct.

Answer (score 0):

Not without other tools.

Unlike C#, Java does not support properties.